# Hyper-V and AWS Linux 2 network connection

Tags: linux, networking, hyper-v

I Followed the instruction on [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-2-virtual-machine.html)  to create a virtual machine that runs AWS Linux on my Windows 10 with Hyper-V. Except for the network everything else works.

Ping to google returns "Name or service not found", ping directly to the IP returns "Destination Host Unreachable"

I see no conflict or errors in the control panel. The Default Switch is being created and assigned to the VM and all looks normal.

So how do I begin to solve this issue? (I have no experience with linux networking)

Thanks,

Comment: default switch is essentially NAT, so you're probably not getting the return communication.  setting a virtual switch with your NIC will probably work better.

Comment: @essjae Setting a virtual switch with my NIC disconnects the host system from the internet... 
How can I debug the issue with the NAT?

Comment: @Eden: Is the host system using static IP configuration?

Comment: @user1686 no, it is dynamically assigned

Comment: we'll need some more info on your network settings, generally your DHCP server will just issue a new IP to your system, but if you're doing something like connecting directly to a modem instead of your own router, you can see issues.  This is especially true if your ISP issues IP addresses assigned to a specific MAC address.  Once you enable the virtual switch on the host's NIC, the "new" virtual NIC will have a different MAC address.